# how to align the image to the center?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, alignment, nextgen-gallery

Why is [the image in this url](http://www.101greatgoals.com/gallery/gimages/image/101com-logofits/), is aligning to the left?

When you load it on chrome, it appears on the left hand side. Do you know why?

Something with the CSS but don't know what.

Thanks!

Comment: The CSS is there - just press F12. The problem is that when the page first loads, the image appears on the left instead of being centered. @RohitAzad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start it's hard to know what you are talking about - it's a page full of images after all.  I'm assuming you mean the '100 Greatest Goals' image in the middle that's been blown up to 10 times it's normal size.

If you change wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/css/nggallery.css line 215 to the following then it centers that images and stops it getting stretched to yee-ha.

```
.ngg-imagebrowser img {
border:1px solid #A9A9A9;
margin: 10px auto; 
display:block !important;
padding:5px;
}
```

Hope that helps a bit.

Edit : Just a point I should have made - whenever you make any changes to Next Gen CSS make sure you add it to your theme's stylesheet rather than the plugin's (using a more specific selector if required). If not your CSS all gets reset after you upgrade the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

this may help

```
.main-image
{
    text-align:center;
}
```